# Special "copy and rename" case

Tags: linux, rename, file-copy

I have a deeply nested folder structure in which there are hundreds of files called `data.log`. I need a script to rename each of these `data.log` files according to the name of the parent folder they are in and then move the renamed filed to a defined target folder. The original `data.log` files should remain in place.

Example:

The file `/opt/slm/data/system/amd-823723/data.log` needs to be renamed to `amd-823723` and then moved to `/opt/slm/output/`, whereby the original `data.log` file remains in place.

Comment: What is the parent directory we are searching?  `/opt/slm/data/system`? `/opt/slm/data`?  Something else?  Will all the new files be in `/opt/slm/output/`?

Comment: Why do you say the file will be moved and at the same time the file remains in place?

Comment: You want to rename each file but then move it and also message the original in place? That sounds like you're actually describing a copy/rename rather then a rename/move/keep.

Comment: "The file /opt/slm/data/system/amd-823723/data.log needs to be renamed to amd-823723." The parent directory is the directory in which the "data.log" file is. The file "data.log" should be copied to the output and renamed to its original parent folder.  Sorry for not being clear enough on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTDIR=/opt/slm/output/

find /opt/slm/data -name data.log |
while read FILE; do

  OUTFILE="$(basename "$(dirname "$FILE")")"
  cp -p "$FILE" "$OUTDIR$OUTFILE"

done
```

Comment: ok, I made it work but more quoting was needed: OUTFILE="$(basename "$(dirname "$FILE")")"

Comment: This will fail when you have files with newline. Use `find -print0` and maybe something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677546/reading-null-delimited-strings-through-a-bash-loop, or `xargs -0`.

Comment: It solved it for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n -C '**/(*)/data.log' '/opt/slm/output/$1'
```

remove the `-n` (for dry run) if happy.

The `-C` is for *copy* (as oppose to *rename*/`mv`) as even though your description says *rename*, it looks like you want to *copy* the files instead into the `output` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find -exec`:

```
find /opt/slm/data -name data.log -exec sh -c '
      TARGET="/opt/slm/output/$(basename "$(dirname "$1")")";
      cp -i "$1" "$TARGET"
    ' find-sh {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

the solution only works for directory names without spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash
targetDir=/opt/slm/output/
for myPath in `find /opt/slm/data/system |grep "data.log$"`
do
    newName = `echo "$myPath" |awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} /data.log/ {print $(NF-1)}'`
    cp "$myPath" ${targetDir}"${newName}"
done
```

**in fact all the given solutions, including mine, are wrong because they lead to the loss of information** for the catalogs:

```
a/a/data.log
a/data.log
b/a/data.log
```

all will have the name "a" and will be overwritten with the last file b / a / data.log

this problem is solved by the example program in python3:

```
import os
for x in (os.walk('/opt/slm/data/system')):
     if x[2] == ['data.log']:
        newName=x[0].replace('/','#').replace(' ','_')
        os.system('cp "'+str(x[0])+'/data.log" /opt/slm/output/'+str(newName))
```

Creates names that contain the full path and the _ character instead of the space:

```
#opt#slm#data#system#dirname
```

Of course, naming and paths have to be adapted to your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much, Slawomir! I will try that out asap and let you know.

Comment: "cp: cannot stat ‘Library)/Sub/C0013S01/data.log’: No such file or directory
cprn.sh: line 5: newName: command not found". That what I get as bash output.

Comment: in the example you provided, there were no parentheses') or space in the names of directories and then it works perfectly. You must therefore adjust the $myPath call to add escape sequences before each special character in the name. I can check it out only for a dozen or so hours.

Comment: check now, I added a protection against a space in the name of the path.

Comment: -1 , because: 1. Do not use loops like this. Never. 2. Do not use `grep` to filter find results. `find` is just perfect for doing exactly this. 3. `awk` seems to be clever here, but keep in mind that filenames are allowed to have newline. This will make your `awk` fail.

Comment: you can give the reason for saying "Do not use loops like this. Never." ? Where can you read about it? I will be happy to explain the justification. "filenames are allowed to have newline." - does anyone really use 'newline' in the file name? Any real example?
As for find and grep, you're right with the fact that there are various implementations and the grep solution is the simplest one to understand. The additional grep process does not fundamentally change performance, and besides, I wrote under the code that you can bypass the grep call and rely solely on the AWK regex.

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: thank you @Stéphane Chazelas, very useful link. Nevertheless, it does not find problems only a very poor practice of using names other than [a-zA-Z0-9_] in names.

Answer (score -1):

Bash:

```
while read -r line; do
    copy="/opt/slm/output/$(sed 's/^.*\/\(.*\)\/data.log/\1/' <<<$line)"
    cp -v "$line" "$copy"
done <<<"/opt/slm/data/system/amd-823723/data.log"
```

Seems like a simple enough solution. Replace `<<<"/opt/slm/data/system/amd-823723/data.log"` with appropriate find command, or something such.

Comment: ```copy="/opt/slm/output/$(awk -F'/' '{print $NF}' <(dirname $line))"``` is probably neater and easier to follow, though.

Comment: Your `while` should be `while IFS=`, otherwise it will eat leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: `sed` and `awk` are both a bad idea as they both work on a line-basis and file names are allowed to have newlines. Your loop will already fail on this.

Comment: It's very corner-case with newline filenames, but you are correct.